# React Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid tag:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm getting a few errors in the browsers console

```
Warning: Element: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. 

Warning: Element: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. 

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: {StrainGrid}
```

Weird thing is, webpack isn't spitting out any error.

This is my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import sass from './styles/style.scss';

import Main from './components/Main';
import Single from './components/Single';
import StrainGrid from './components/StrainGrid';

import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const router = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <IndexRoute component={StrainGrid}></IndexRoute>
      <Route path="/view/:postId" component={Single}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And this is Main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

const Main = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1><Link to="/">Strain Guide</Link></h1>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
      </div>
    )
  }
});


export default Main;
```

StrainGrid component:

```
import React from 'react';

const StrainGrid = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="straing-grid">
          Grid
        </div>
    )
  }
});

export default StrainGrid;
```

Any help would be great. Don't know why Im getting these.

Comment: Can you show the `StrainGrid` component? Also, perhaps unrelated to your error, but the Route path should be `view/:postId` without the leading `/`.

Comment: @Chris added to original answer

Comment: Can you provide the versions of your [tag:react] and [tag:react-router] modules?

Comment: @Chris Using the latest react. Not using react-bootstrap

Comment: oops, I meant [tag:react-router]. Please provide the versions anyway :)

Comment: @Chris   "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-router": "^2.4.1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113824/discussion-between-chris-and-dileet).

Answer (score 2):

React Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid tag:

Change this:

```js
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)}
```

to

```js
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props })
```